grafana table panel unable to sort by columns
We are using grafana 9.1.8 and created sample table as below. We are unable to click on column headers to sort based on column values.
(it is simple table no transforms, overrides, etc)


We spent lot of time for the reason behind this by comparing json of two table panels where one is sortable.
At last we noticed that for table that dont have title, the column headers overlap with the panel title space and unable to click on column header for sort (overlap with panel title).
However if we add panel title the column headers go one step below and allow sort as usual.
Not sure if Grafana has to consider as bug and resolve this by changing the width of those two headers.

